# Move firebase child node to top when onChildChanged() method is called

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nodes

Here's my firebase database structure...
[image]

I want to move the node marked with red to the top under messages when there is change in data under node marked with green. How this can be achieved.

Here's my code...

```
 ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { //ref is reference to messages node
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) 
        {

        }
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        //Here i need to implement this function
        }
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys in your firebase console will always be alphabetically ordered and you can't change that.

What you can do though is create a key in which to store your data under which would be sorted correctly. For example a timestamp key.

Comment: Can you share any references or example?

Comment: can this be achieved using pushid?

Comment: Depends on your project, but if your key is a timestamp you need to keep your data under this. Otherwise you could create a new node entirely and call it "NewestMessage" and then overwrite the data here when new data is saved

Comment: If there's an edit in any of photoUrl by any user.his user node should be on top. or if we did this by timestamp then the nodes will be arranged by descending order from latest to old time.

Comment: I think the best way to keep track of this, is to create a new node for storing the newest message, and then whenever a user edits their photourl this node will be updated with their id and a timestamp, and then be overwritten every time a new edit occurs